# Many try/except, sequential trials

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why does this not print 'asdf'?

How do I make it so that no error appears and `asdf` is printed.

```
try:
    1/0
except:
    pass
else:
    print 'asdf'
```

More generally, how would I set up something like if, elif, elif, elif.... with try, elsetry, elsetry.... or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this not print 'asdf'?

The `else` clause of a `try` statement is only run if *no exception* occurs.

> How do I make it so that no error appears and `asdf` is printed.

Either have no exception occur, or use the `finally` clause instead.

```
try:
   ...
finally:
  print 'asdf'
```